# SQL Server unable to trim data of COLLATION type SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: sql-server, collation, trim

We've two database one is the old one which has COLLATION - SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and the new one with COLLATION - Latin1_General_CI_AI (probably the default one).

There's a simple Table1 (ID (int), code(nvarchar(50))) in both the databases. What I'm suppose to do is compare both the tables for its data and find the missing or extra records.

```
Sample data in old table has code like : 'Code1      '
Sample data in new table has code like : 'Code1  '
```

What I need to be able to do is compare both the data (from the 'Name' column). I'm unable to trim the data from the old table -

**EXAMPLE:**

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([Name])) from [OLDDB].dbo.Table1
returns 'Code1     '       -- NOT as expected (probably due to mis-match in charset

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([Name])) from [NEWDB].dbo.Table1
'Code1'                    -- as expected
```

I hope it makes sense. Besides, even if I changes the COLLATION at column level still I was not able to get the ltrim / rtrim work!

Thanks.

Comment: I just created two databases with these exact collations, tried the code and haven't encountered such behavior. Is it possible that the column data in OLDDB contain some other kind of white spaces, for example CHAR(160) that RTRIM doesn't trim? Check it with `SELECT Name FROM OLDDB.dbo.Table1
WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(160), Name) <> 0`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it does seem to be the char(160), I checked the above query and returns non-zero. Anyway to derive an LTRIM RTRIM based on that? I believe changing COLLATION at each column level is a long process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CHAR(160) is the problem, then you don't have to change collation. Just replace those CHAR(160) with proper spaces and then RTRIM will work.

`SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([Name], CHAR(160), ' '))) from [OLDDB].dbo.Table1`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below update, Hope this will fix the issue.

update [OLDDB].dbo.Table1 set Name RTRIM(replace(NAME, char(160), char(32)))

Comment: DB is too big and applying change on all tables is not an easy option.